# SQLite append to Null or not NULL

Tags: sqlite

I'm relatively new to this whole SQLite/database thing. I'm trying to append text to a field that may be NULL or may have a text value. For example, the field "Date" may be NULL or may have "1/1/1" in it, and I would like to append ", 1/2/1" to it for a total effect of 1/1/1, 1/2/1. If the field is NULL, it would read ", 1/2/1".

Here's my attempt at the code, or at least one:

`UPDATE 'History_data'
SET 
CASE (Date IS NULL) THEN Date = ", 1/2/1"
ELSE Date = Date || ", 1/2/1"
END
WHERE Field='Something'`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You are making a big design mistake in storing more than one value in a single column.  That violates a fundamental rule of relational database design.  Instead of one row with two values in one column, you should have two rows with one value each.

Comment: The name of that rule is "first normal form".

Comment: Good to know! Thank you -- so, is there an easy way to store data in first normal form such that it would be sequential as well? I.E. dates in order?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite documentation has excellent syntax diagrams. On [this one](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) you can see that the proper syntax is SET column_name = expression, so it should be something like:

```
... SET Date = (CASE (Date IS NULL) THEN ", 1/2/1" ELSE Date || ", 1/2/1" END)
```

I haven't tested it, so there might be other syntax errors, but in that case just follow the diagrams from docs and you should be able to find it easily.

Comment: Thank you! I got the syntax down too:

<code>
UPDATE 'History_data'
SET Date = 
  CASE   WHEN Date IS NULL THEN  '123'
  ELSE  Date || '456'
  END
WHERE Field= 'Something'
</code>